# Best practice for populating a property of an entity object which requires a second database call

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wpf

I'm running a commercial accounting software packages which uses a SQL server database. I've also developed a WPF application which is basically a slimmed down version of the commercial software.

Using the commercial software, I can open up an account and see such info as the name of the account holder, which of our clients he has an account with, how much money he owes on the account, etc.

My problem is this: the process for determining the amount due on the account is pretty involved. In order to retrieve the value, the commercial product calls a function which in turn calls a method in a dll which is installed in the SQL server. There's no other way to get this value accurately and consistently.

Understandably, this value is used quite a bit throughout my app. Therefore, I'd like to make AmountDue a property of the Account entity object.

At the moment, I'm using a partial Account class which has a property like so:

```cs
public partial class Account
{
  //The Claim_Result object contains a few different values (amount due, fees due, 
  //interest due, etc)
  private Claim_Result claim;
  public Claim_Result Claim
  {
    get
    {
      if (claim == null)
      {
        claim = GetClaim();
      }

      return claim;
    }
  }

  private double? due;
  public double Due
  {
    get
    {
      if (due.HasValue == false)
      {
        due = 0;

        if (Claim != null)
        {
          due = Claim.AmountDue;
        }
      }

      return due ?? 0;
    }
  }

  //Make DB call to retrieve Claim values
  private Claim_Result GetClaim()
  {
    Claim_Result result = null;

    //My Entities object contains a static DbConnection object that is created whenever 
    //I call a constructor of the Entities object. I use it so I'll know which db I should 
    //connect to
    if (Entities.Connection != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entities.Connection.ConnectionString) == false)
    {
      using (var db = new Entities(Entities.Connection, false))
      {
        result = db.ClaimWrapper(this.AccountNo).FirstOrDefault();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception("You're screwed!");
    }

    return result;
  }
}

public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
  public static DbConnection Connection = new EntityConnection("default connection string");

  public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
  {
    Connection = new EntitityConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
  }
}
```

So, I've got two problems. The first is that I've been told over and over that it's a bad idea to make a DB call from a property getter. So, what's the best way to get this value and store it in a property? I'd like to use a property because I'd like to bind to the property.

The second, and more complicated problem is that I've got development and production databases. Within my Account object, I don't actually know which of the databases I'm working with. So, I've jerry-rigged a way to check where I am. But, I'm sure there's a much better way to do this and there are surely a million reasons not to do it the way I currently am.

So, how SHOULD I be going about this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to create a view in the commercial DB?

If so, then a sound approach to this may be to write the version of 'account' that you want to read as a view and design you application to read from this instead of 'directly' from the tables.  This view can contain AmountDue as a column.

This gives a secondary advantage that your application is reliant on a layer above the actual DB tables, so if these change significantly (which is outside your control), you may get away with just updating the view instead of the code.

Comment: Though it's not quite the solution I'm looking for, this is definitely a solution. My main concern is that there are multiple properties like AmountDue that I'd like to load into the Account object. I'd like to use lazy loading for performance sake rather than using a view which gathers every piece of data whether I need it or not. But, this may be the method that I go with.

Comment: @TroyFrazier - particularly as you don't have control of the underlying database (and I assume will not be writing to it), then this technique has definite advantages.

Comment: I totally agree. Under different circumstances, it would be a great solution. Unfortunately for me 1) the function returns a table value instead of a scalar value (which means using cross apply), and 2) the function in question is already pretty slow. Selecting the first 1000 rows where the client's name is Martin goes from a matter of milliseconds to 35 seconds. I really need to grab this value only when it's needed, and then only once.